# replace pagination numbers by custom text datatable

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the datatable. Can I write the number of record in the page to the page number and it will change denpend on the number of record that is showing
SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH

from: [1][2][3][4][5][6]
to: [1-10][11-20][21-30][31-40][41-50][51-60]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geCNd.png)

Comment: Do you mean you're using Datatables.js to render the table, or that you have a static table of data in your HTML? If you're working with static HTML, the answer from Atanas below is correct: define the links as you require in your HTML. If you're using Datatables.js, you can't do what you're asking (I don't think): although you can configure how pagination works, the actual buttons use page numbers rather than record numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that pagination is a ul>li element therefore simple html, you can shange the text inside it like that:

```
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1-10</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">11-20</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">21-30</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">31-40</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">41-50</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">51-60</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```